# How to edit a .raf file?

Tags: text, binary

I am trying to open and edit a .raf file (maybe the Fuji RAW Image File, the result file of a software named SleepSign http://www.sleepsign.com/ ). But I faild to convert it to text file,such as .txt,which I could edit easily and replace the result to what I want. So I can load the replaced-file in SleepSign for manual correction.  I test almost all the ways to convert or edit it, but it always break down with a error.I hope for some advises or tools to solve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can trie with this one : https://www.onlineconvert.com/by/raf-to-txt-converter.

for infoemration .RAF is a .RAW priority format created by Fuji.